# Water flow measuring device for a simple ceramic water filter

Tags: measurements, fluid-filtration, water-pressure

I am looking for a solution that would allow me to measure water consumption from a simple ceramic water filter device (see picture below).

The meter must be relatively cheap, work without being plugged to the electricity, and be able to to measure low water flows. The PVC faucet has an external diameter of 3/4".

[image: Ceramic water filter design, taken from McBean, E., et al. 2018. "Ceramic Water Filters as a Response Technology to Geo-Hazards."]

Comment: What have you found and discarded already?

Comment: I've found 
- micro flow meters (e.g., used in coffee vendor machines), they are highly accurate but very expensive (more than 200USD)
- flow meters to be attached to a garden hose might not work because of their minimum operating flow is much higher than the one of a 20L bucket full of water (however I could buy one and test it)

Comment: There is a very simple and accurate measuring device for measuring mass.  It uses a fulcrum, a lever, and balance weights so no electricity whatsoever!  Proven over thousands of years. You just use it any time (before & after) you add water and any time you want a measurement thereafter.

Comment: Could you provide a link with picture and description please? Is there a way to allow this device to keep count of multiple mesurements automatically?

Comment: Typical residential water meter seems suitable. Easy to buy, accurate, inexpensive and reliable. There are models with electrical contacts that cost just little more. 1/2" with adapters will be cheaper and more suitable, i think.

Comment: I've finally decided to try a standard residential meter. Its precision is of 0.001 m3 (which is good enough for my purpose). My only concern if it will work with very low pressures.  I will post if it works.